# Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'table-box'

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Tengo un problema al momento de querer generar un ngFor  en Angular 2

ese es el código que quiero insertar.

```js
import {Component , Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Tabla} from '../common/tabla';
@Component({
 selector: 'table-box',
 templateUrl: './table-box.html' 
})
export class tableBoxcomponent{
 @Input()
 table: Tabla;
}
```

```html
  <tr class="table">
       <th> {{table.name}} </th>
        <td> <button class="btn btn-info"> detalle </button></td>
        <td>  </td>
    </tr>
```

este es el que lo insertara mediante un *ngFor

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Tabla} from '../../common/tabla';
const TABLE : Tabla[] = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'SUELDO BASE',
  detail:{
   tipodoc: "string",
   numbrdoc: 12345,
   detalle: "string",
   fechadoc: "string",
   fechapag: "string",
   rutproov:"string",
   nombreproov: "string",
   montodecl: 123,
   montodoc: 123,
   numbrdocorig: 123
  }
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'HORAS EXTRAS',
  detail:{
   tipodoc: "string",
   numbrdoc: 12345,
   detalle: "string",
   fechadoc: "string",
   fechapag: "string",
   rutproov:"string",
   nombreproov: "string",
   montodecl: 123,
   montodoc: 123,
   numbrdocorig: 123
  }
 }

];

 @Component({
 selector: 'tables',
 templateUrl: './tables.html'

})

export class Tables{
 title:string = 'hola mundo';
 tabl: Tabla [] = TABLE;
}

y mi app.Module es 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

el error al agregar el ngFor es :

```js
zone.js:630 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'table-box'.
1. If 'table-box' is an Angular component and it has 'ngForFor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'table-box' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
     <table-box
     [table] = "table"
     [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let table for tabl">
     </table-box>

"): ng:///AppModule/Tables.html@4:5
Property binding ngForFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("  <table class="table table-striped">
     <h1></h1>
     [ERROR ->]<table-box
     [table] = "table"
     *ngFor="let table for tabl">
"): ng:///AppModule/Tables.html@2:5 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'table-box'.
1. If 'table-box' is an Angular component and it has 'ngForFor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'table-box' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
     <table-box
     [table] = "table"
     [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let table for tabl">
     </table-box>

"): ng:///AppModule/Tables.html@4:5
Property binding ngForFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("  <table class="table table-striped">
     <h1></h1>
     [ERROR ->]<table-box
     [table] = "table"
     *ngFor="let table for tabl">
"):
```

ya he buscado y re leído todo el código, sin poder encontrar mi error. alguna ayuda? que me estoy perdiendo? muchas gracias

Comment: tengo otros ngfor que funcionan bien, es solo este el del problema :C

Comment: Me vas a perdonar, pero no veo donde estás haciendo el ngFor. Puedes pegar el código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No veo como te decía en el comentario donde intentas hacer el ngFor aún así leyendo más despacio el error que te devuelve puede que el problema este en la sintaxis.

Estás haciendo.

```
*ngFor="let table for tabl
```

Cuando la sintaxis correcta sería

`*ngFor="let table of tabl`

Como ves es "of" en lugar de "for"

Comment: que ciego de mi parte, el error estuvo frente a mis narices tanto tiempo, perdí casi 3 días buscando el maldito error, muchas gracias <3

Comment: Es muy muy muy muy típico sobre todo si vienes de programar en Angular JS. Yo lo he tenido ya dos o tres veces, de estar desesperado como tú y me lo grabé a fuego ya. Es lo primero que miro cuando me da problemas un ngFor jajaja.